# $f(x)$ and $f(x^2)$ differentiable at $0$, then $f’(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Is it true that if $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f(x ^ 2)$ is differentiable at $0$ then $f ’(0) = 0$?

Could you please help me, I affirm that this is not true, since $f (x) = x + 1$ is a counterexample, but my teacher has told me that this is true.  I appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: You are right. Or the question is uncomplete.

Comment: Maybe the claim is actually that $\frac{d}{dx} f(x^2)$ at $x=0$ is $0$?